# Account information is being deleted with password reset from edit in user controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, change-password

I'm attempting to create a web app with an admin section where account information can be seen and edited using MVC, razor and the entity framework (code first). My problem is that when I try and reset the password using a controller the rest of the account information is deleted. Here is my controller

```
    // GET: Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        ApplicationUser applicationUser = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (applicationUser == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }

    // POST: Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id, EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, Department, Supervisor, Email, UserName, Password, Confirm Password")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(applicationUser.Email);
            applicationUser.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
            string resetToken = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var pass = Request["Password"];
            IdentityResult passwordChangeResult = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, resetToken, Request["Password"]);

            db.Entry(applicationUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```

When debugging and stepping through the code and looking into the database I see that a password is hashed and stored correctly up until `db.SaveChanges();`, after stepping over that line the password is then deleted, but the rest of the information is saved. So I figured maybe moving the password reset process to be after that line would help, but then the extra information that was edited is deleted, while the password is saved. So I can't seem to find out why this is the case. I've found other posts, but they say the solution is to either encode the token, replace the spaces with '+' or to time stamp it, but from reading those it seems the reset process that I'm writing is correct and it seems to me that I have a bit of a different situation here. The token verification is coming up as successful as well and a time stamp remains throughout the process. Maybe someone can shed some insight and tell my why I'm having the problem I'm having? It would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using the ApplicationUser model and it is shown below.

```
namespace ReconciliationApp.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Supervisor { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ReconciliationContext")
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ReconciliationApp.Models.RegisterViewModel> RegisterViewModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also let me know if you need any more information that might seem relevant as well!

Comment: `db.Entry(applicationUser).State = EntityState.Modified;` and `db.SaveChanges();` are not required.  Why are you trying to update the user if Asp.NET Identity is already doing that for you? If you need to change the security stamp, you can call `UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497579%28v=vs.108%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: That is not true, if you look at my controller I'm binding in other information as well (EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, etc.) and that information will not be posted to the database if I leave 'db.Entry(applicationUser).State = EntityState.Modified;' and 'db.SaveChanges();' out. I even tried it out to confirm.

Comment: Actually I figured it out, you pointed me in the right direction with looking at how I was writing the security stamp, that now seems pretty obvious. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it seems that I just needed to set everything individually rather than all at once. I think I was just trying to base this controller on some of the scaffolded controllers that I have and use. Here is my working code.

```
    // POST: CSReconForms/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id, EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, Department, Supervisor, Email, UserName, Password, Confirm Password")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //UserManager.Create<applicationu>();
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(applicationUser.Email);
            //applicationUser.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
            user.EmployeeNumber = applicationUser.EmployeeNumber;
            user.FirstName = applicationUser.FirstName;
            user.LastName = applicationUser.LastName;
            user.Department = applicationUser.Department;
            user.Supervisor = applicationUser.Supervisor;

            string resetToken = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var pass = Request["Password"];
            IdentityResult passwordChangeResult = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, resetToken, Request["Password"]);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```